# Python script to watermark a pdf with pages of sizes like A3 ,A2 at the center

Tags: python, pdf, watermark

My current script is rotating the watermark by 90 when page size is bigger like A2. For page A3 size it’s watermarking as required.

Need your recommendation to fix this issue. I have been using PyPDF2 library but this is not getting me the expected results

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on the code you used? Maybe checking the page size and rotation more adequately will help.

Comment: I am able to get the page length and width but unable to detect orientation using the reader.page.get(‘/Rotate’) the error suggests that this has been deprecated in the PyPDF2 package.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.